# user merge fields doesn't replace by user record ID

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to send email through email template to user but It is always replacing the user merge fields by org admin's user name instead of targetobjectID user.

Org admin : luke wright

### **Email template Body :**

```
Dear {!User.Name} ,
Hearty Congratulations on this beautiful occasion. May your marriage bring great joy, love and passion in your life. I wish to God to bless you with a wonderful marriage and a happy life ahead.
Thanks and Regards.
{!Organization.Name}
```

---

```
OrgWideEmailAddress owa = [select id, DisplayName, Address from OrgWideEmailAddress limit 1];
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); 
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
mail.setTemplateID('00X0S000000iBYB'); // Template Id
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
mail.setTargetObjectId('0050S0000023KS9'); // UserId  Name: John Doe
mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owa.id);
allmsg.add(mail); 
Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);
```

---

**Issue:** Dear `{!User.Name}`  should be replace by **john doe** while it is replacing by **luke wright** and email goes to correct user i.e.   **john doe**

**P.S.**  User's merge fields is not replacing by that record ID

Comment: Can you try using `{!Contact.Name}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User error? ;)

`User` is for current running user. Looks like you want `Receiving_User`.

If you have Communities enabled you probably have this built-in email template. And even if not - check the top of the screenshot.

[image]

And if your email template is Visualforce rather than normal - probably you should be using `{!relatedTo}`.